# How can I implement Objective-C libraries in Unity?

Tags: unity, objective-c

I've been a "hardcore" developer for sometime now, as I've always worked with pure code reactive rendering, and contributed to `Cocos2d` library some time ago , (It is the one I used for my games) . But **I've come to realize that most of the work I'm doing by setting up my game environment , user interface and everything else is becoming a bit repetitive, and complicated**, as position must be tested each build , debugging sometimes involves exploring the deep down framework and I've decided to try out a full game development environment.

Some friends have recommended me `Unity` for mobile development (If you could give me any better advice I'd be grateful) but my main concern is my custom libraries I built on Objective C for multiplayer real time connectivity, it's probably thousands of lines and I wouldn't like to write them all over again.

**Is there any way I could invoke my objective-c library in Unity ?**

I know it's probably a vague question but can't seem to find where to start! Any guidance will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Seems you could convert it to a Unity plugin http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Plugins.html. Never used unity though so I'll let more people exspand on if that is practical or even possible.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion and honesty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plugins for Unity can be written using Objective C; refer to this page: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

However I wouldn't assume that a code library of thousands of lines that wasn't designed to be used as a Unity plugin will work as a Unity plugin. It's all free so you could download Unity, fire up the demo project, and then try to integrate your Objective C library.

Comment: Assuming the free version of Unity can load this kind of plugin? Well, anyway there's a 1-month free trial of the paid version.

Comment: The free version can load plugins for iOS and Android but not for standalone.